# Sql Server Last Login detail

Tags: sql-server

I need a query in SQL Server which can list all the logins and their last login details.

The requirement is to find all the windows and SQL logins which have not been used in the last 6 months. We have 100 logins on one SQL instance but most of the AD accounts have been removed but the logins still exist in Sql server.

Comment: For the Windows/AD logins... you can get the binary SID and Name from sys.server_principals and compare those against what's still existing in AD. There are plenty of examples out there converting a binary SID to a text formatted one like you'd see out of wmic useraccounts and Get-ADUser.

Comment: @GuidoG `sys.dm_exec_sessions` is useles as it only shows curerntly logged in users

Comment: Best is to set up an XEvents session to keep track of all logins. Then you simply query the XEvents XML for the most recent login event for each user.